# Apache Tika - detect JSON / PDF specific mime type

Tags: java, mime-types, apache-tika

I'm using [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) to detect a file Mime Type from its **base64** rapresentation.
Unfortunately I don't have other info about the file (e.g. extension).

Is there something I can do to make Tika be more specific?

I'm currently using this:

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
tika.setMaxStringLength(-1);
String mimetype = tika.detect(Base64.decode(fileString));
```

and it gives me `text/plain` for JSON and PDF files, but I would like to obtain a more specific information: `application/json`, `application/pdf` etc...

Hope someone can help me!

Thanks.

Comment: `Base64.decode(fileString).getBytes()` is all you need to get PDFs detected properly. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48619266/344029) for the JSON part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`Tika#detect(String)`**

> Detects the media type of a document with the given file name.

Passing the content of a PDF or JSON file won't work as [this method expects a filename](https://tika.apache.org/1.17/api/org/apache/tika/Tika.html#detect-java.lang.String-). Tika will fallback to `text/plain` as it won't find any matching filenames.

**PDF**

For PDF, you just need to either write some of the data to a stream, or pass it some of the bytes and have Tika read that using [Mime Magic Detection](https://tika.apache.org/1.16/detection.html#Mime_Magic_Detection) by looking for special ("magic") patterns of bytes near the start of the file (which in plain text is `%PDF`):

```java
String pdfContent = "%PDF-1.4\n%\\E2\\E3\\CF\\D3"; // i.e. base64 decoded
Tika tika = new Tika();
System.out.println(tika.detect(pdfContent.getBytes())); // "application/pdf"
```

**JSON**

For JSON though, even this method will return `text/plain` & Tika is correct. `application/json` is like a subtype of plain text to indicate that the text should be interpreted differently. So that's what you'll have to do if you get `text/plain`. Use a JSON library (e.g. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)) to parse the content to see if it's valid JSON:

```java
Sring json = "[1, 2, 3]"; // an array in JSON
try {
    final JsonParser parser = new ObjectMapper().getFactory().createParser(json);
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    }
    System.out.println("Probably JSON!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Definitely not JSON!");
}
```

Just be careful about how strict you want to be since Jackson treats a single number `1` as valid JSON but it's not really. To get round that, you could 1st of all test that the string starts with either `{` or `[` (possibly preceded by whitespace) using something like `json.matches("^\\s*[{\\[].*")` before even attempting to parse it as JSON.

Here's a [DZone tutorial for Jackson](https://dzone.com/articles/processing-json-with-jackson).

Answer (score 4):

In my past project I used `TikaConfig`

What I did is:

```
//Note you can use alse byte[] instead of InputStream
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(YOUR_FILE));
TikaConfig tc = new TikaConfig();
Metadata md = new Metadata();
md.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName);
String mimeType = tc.getDetector().detect(TikaInputStream.get(is), md).toString();
```

By using `byte[]`:

```
byte[] fileBytes = GET_BYTE_ARRAY_FROM_YOUR_FILE;
TikaConfig tc = new TikaConfig();
Metadata md = new Metadata();
md.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName);
String mimeType = tc.getDetector().detect(TikaInputStream.get(fileBytes), md).toString();
```

I had no issue in getting the right mimeType....

I hope it is useful

Angelo

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that I don't have the file name, just the base64 string representation of the file.

Comment: You may use a fake file name

Comment: But his problem with Tika not giving the exact mimeType - application/json instead of text/plain would still remain

Comment: If you check the stream, it will be application/json. Wht you should do is to write a temporary file and then let Tika to check the temporary file

Comment: Agreed that Tika is being "lazy" with JSON files. The same is true with CSV files which result in `text/plain` rather than `text/csv`.